# How to connect to a Notes DB from an Apache Server

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I hope I use the propper terminology. Please correct me if not.

How to access an .nsf file with PHP ? I need to get some field values of tables for clients login purposes around the globe. Let`s say I need to validate if a client is registered and that value is stored in an xyz.nsf file. How to connect and how access it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Access your data with http/https request per URL.

You have several choices:

1. use out-of-the-box [Domino URL commands](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_DOMINO_URL_COMMANDS_4332.html?lang=en) like [URL commands for opening documents by key](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_URL_COMMANDS_FOR_OPENING_DOCUMENTS_BY_KEY.html?lang=en)
2. use [IBM Domino Access Services (DAS)](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Domino%20Access%20Services%209.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=IBM_Domino_Access_Services_overview_das901&content=apicontent)
3. create your own REST service based on [ExtLib REST Service](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/extlib_controlref_restservice.html?lang=en)
4. create an XAgent which delivers the data as JSON ([see example](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=example-json-data-provider-using-gson-and-an-xagent))
5. [create your own Domino REST service using DAS](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Create_your_own_Domino_REST_service_using_DAS)

Choice #1 returns HTML. All others return JSON data which is probably best to handle with PHP. I'd go for choice #3 ExtLib REST Service.